# creating a linked list + add new node + print the list and cannot figure out why it's not working

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

so i am trying to create a linked list, that has a function to add a new node at the beggining of the list, and then print the list out. i am a novice coder and am still learning how to do this, when i execute the code, nothing prints ..

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char DATA;
struct node
{
    DATA d;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *header = NULL;
    struct node *second = NULL;
    struct node *third = NULL;

    header->d = 'a';
    header->next = second;

    second->d = 'b';
    second->next = third;

    third->d = 'c';
    third->next = NULL;

    struct addnew;

    printList(header);
}

struct node *addnew(node, d, header)
{
    struct node *addnew = header;

    addnew->d = 'k';
    addnew->next = header;

    return addnew;
}

int printList(node, next, header)
{
    struct node *current = header;

    while (next != 'NULL')
    {
        printf('/c', current->d);
        current = current->next;
    }

    return current->d;
}
```

Comment: There are so many errors in your program. Try reading a book first, make yourself familiar how memory is managed in c/c++. To give you a hint. You never create a node you need something like malloc/new.

Comment: You're trying to reference a lot of NULL pointers (*e.g.*, `struct node *header = NULL;` followed by `header->d = 'a'`).  And what's the purpose of `struct addnew;` all by itself in the middle of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program can look the following way (without testing)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char Data ;

struct node 
{
    Data d ;
    struct node *next ;
};

struct node * addNew( struct node *head, Data value )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    if ( new_node != NULL )
    {
        new_node->d = value;
        new_node->next = head;
        head = new_node;
    }

    return head;
}

void printList( struct node *head )
{
    for ( ; head; head = head->next ) printf( "%c ", head->d );
}

struct node * freeList( struct node *head )
{
    while ( head != NULL )
    {
        struct node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return head;
}

int main( void )
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    head = addNew( head, 'a' );
    head = addNew( head, 'b' );
    head = addNew( head, 'c' );

    printList( head );
    printf( "\n" );

    head = freeList( head );
}
```

As for your code then it contains many errors. For example you did not allocate memory for elements of the list. You only defined pointers to elements that were not allocated and assigned NULL to these pointers.

```
struct node *header = NULL;
struct node *second = NULL;
struct node *third = NULL;
```

So next statements

```
header->d = 'a';
header->next = second;
//..
```

are wrong.

Also this declaration

```
struct addnew;
```

makes no sense.

And you did not correctly define the functions.

Comment: thank you very much. obviously i still have heaps to learn and your syntax actually really helped. 

out of cursiosity, what does freelist do? i didn't really understand that.

Comment: @juzuze When new nodes were added to the list they were allocated dynamically useing standard C function malloc. After the list is not needed any more you should free all allocated for the list memory. Function freeList does this task.

Answer (score 0):

@ jazuze lots of errors. Even I'm learning linked lists, its okay. I've commented below the areas you need to correct. I have the compiled your code with the corrections and it works properly but I'm not giving you the solution easily. I suggest you work on the below::

```
    #include <stdio.h>

typedef char DATA ;     //why do you need to typedef char

struct node {
DATA d ;
struct node * next ;
};

int main (){

struct node* header = NULL;
struct node* second = NULL;
struct node* third = NULL;

header->d = 'a';
header->next = second;

second->d = 'b';
second->next = third;

third->d = 'c';
third->next = NULL;

struct addnew;
printList(header);


}

// place all functions before main

struct node* addnew (node, d, header){  //should be struct node* addnew(struct node* header). This whole function needs to be corrected

struct node* addnew = header;   //incorrect logic. You need to malloc addnew first so that you get a new node in memory
addnew->d = 'k';
addnew->next = header;

return addnew;  //you lose the header

}

int printList(node, next, header){  //(node, next, header) what is this?? It should be printList(struct node* header)
struct node *current = header;

while (next != 'NULL'){     // incorrect logic. What is next. Should be (current != NULL)
    printf('/c', current->d);   //should be printf(“%c”, current->d);
    current = current->next;
}

return current->d;      //why return current->d
}
```